# Bootstrap NavBar isn't responsive on IPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working in Bootstrap Studio and can't seem to fix this stupid problem.

I saw everybody suggesting that i should just add
meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0"
to the < head>, but unfortunately, i am unable to edit that part of the code because its locked in BootStrap Studio.

But i did see this in my code:

< head>
< meta charset="utf-8" />
< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
.
.
.
</ head>

Is there any way of removing this shrink-to-fit=“no” tag in Bootstrap Studio without exporting? If not is there a good tutorial on exporting from BootStrap Studio because when i tried doing it ruined everything. Thanks!

Comment: From your question it is not clear what your problem is. Provide context and a sample of your code, so others can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Last time this happened to me I just erase that part of code and rewrote it, and then it worked.Hope this helped!

Comment: But i cannot edit that part of the code, BootStrap Studio does not allow it.

Comment: Oh, when I use flutter I use it with vs code or android studio, I am sorry I could not help.